# Converting varchar into date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below column called "ExpiryDate" and it contains date as per below format

```
15/03/2017 00:00
17/12/2014
13/07/2015
14/09/2016
07/12/2016
27/07/2015
02/09/2015 00:00
11/04/2016 00:00
26/02/2015
19/09/2017 00:00
```

I tried to convert the above column into date by using CAST function

```
  select CAST([ExpiryDate] AS date) AS Expiry_Date   FROM [dbo].[training]
```

Getting below error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 23
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Is anyone can advise how to convert? I checked other posts but no success.

Comment: don't use `CAST` use [CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with style `103` for format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

As others already suggested, it is better not to use `CAST()`. It will error out on an improper string.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _date VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @tbl (_date) VALUES
('15/03/2017 00:00'),
('17/12/2014'),
('13/07/2015'),
('14/09/2016'),
('07/12/2016'),
('27/07/2015'),
('02/09/2015 00:00'),
('11/04/2016 00:00'),
('26/02/2015'),
('19/09/2017 00:00');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT * 
    , TRY_CAST(LEFT(_date, 10) AS DATE) AS Expiration_Date
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | _date | Expiration_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/03/2017 00:00 | 2017-03-15 |
| 2 | 17/12/2014 | 2014-12-17 |
| 3 | 13/07/2015 | 2015-07-13 |
| 4 | 14/09/2016 | 2016-09-14 |
| 5 | 07/12/2016 | 2016-12-07 |
| 6 | 27/07/2015 | 2015-07-27 |
| 7 | 02/09/2015 00:00 | 2015-09-02 |
| 8 | 11/04/2016 00:00 | 2016-04-11 |
| 9 | 26/02/2015 | 2015-02-26 |
| 10 | 19/09/2017 00:00 | 2017-09-19 |

Comment: Why not TRY_CONVERT with style 103? Then it can be used in contexts where arbitrarily changing DATEFORMAT might not be feasible.